# iOS - Casting UIView to UIButton/other views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I will be creating UIButton and other views programmatically. The buttons will be created inside custom class call ButtonBuilder. This builder class will be the subclass of BaseBuilder class. The classes are as shown below.

## BaseBuilder Class

```
- (id)init{
     self = [super init];
     if (0 != self) {
        baseView = [[UIView alloc]init]; //baseView is a property of BaseBuilder class
     }
     return self;
  }

//Real implementation of build class is more complicated than just setting 
//the background color and frame size
-(void)build{ 
     baseView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     baseView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
 }
```

## ButtonBuilder Class

```
-(void)build:(UIView*) view{ 
     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
     [super build];
     button = (UIButton*)baseView;
     button.text = @"ButtonText"; // other button settings will be added here

     [view addSubview:button]; // view is view from main view controller
}
```

I know that casting UIView to UIButton is not possible in iOS. Thus, I need advice on alternative to casting views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use a view in a button, without having tested the code:

```
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
[view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addSubview:view];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not cast `UIView` to `UIButton`. If you have to do something like that Try creating a new button instance and just set all the properties of view to button. But I don't understand much what are you trying to do.

```
-(void)build:(UIView*) view{ 
  [super build];
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setFrame:baseView.frame];
[btn setBackgroundColor:view.backgroundColor];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[view addSubview:btn];
}
```